# Enable Full Indexer in Eclipse-C++

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse for a C++ project. I generally get option "Open Declaration" to switch from a particular place to its declaration.

I am looking for option "Open Definition" to swich to the definition of a function. I cam to know that I need to enable "Full Indexer" instead of "Fast Indexer". But I am not fetting the option to enable "Full Indexer" in my Eclipse.

I tried to find in the following path

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I always press F3 to open declaration, then F3 again to open definition. This works almost all the time (apart from indexer bugs).